# Cannot download bundle at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/....oss-catalog-1.6.jar: HTTP Server 'Not Implemented'

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, tycho

Recently, I re-imaged our machines from Windows 7 to Windows 10. 
Ever since then, on opening Eclipse, I've been unable to open the M2E Catalog. This means I can't install Maven's the Tycho Project Configurator. As this is an organization, it's pretty certain there may be proxy servers. However, I've not been able to obtain its details. Essentially, installing the Tycho Project Configurator is what I'm trying to do.

Steps to reproduce:

```
Eclipse Oxygen -> Quick Access -> "m2e"
```

> Error on Eclipse GUI: "Discovery completed without finding any
>   extensions. Please check your network connection and try again".

Eclipse logs:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery 4 0 2020-02-17 10:48:23.685
>   !MESSAGE Cannot download bundle at
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/discovery-catalog/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.oss-catalog-1.6.jar:
>   HTTP Server 'Not Implemented':
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/discovery-catalog/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.oss-catalog-1.6.jar
>   !STACK 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: HTTP Server
>   'Not Implemented':
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/discovery-catalog/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.oss-catalog-1.6.jar
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.util.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:109)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.util.TransportUtil.downloadResource(TransportUtil.java:56)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy$DownloadBundleJob.call(RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.java:202)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy$DownloadBundleJob.call(RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.java:1)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException:
>   HttpComponents connection error response code 501.    at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:293)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>
> Java version: 1.8.0_181

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try a newer release of Eclipse. Maven Central only provides downloads by https, now.